# Different useMemo and useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

useEffect will execute the function when there was re-render occurs and when the state value is changed. The useMemo also work similar like useEffect where it Will execute the function when there was re-render occurs and when the state value was change.

But what is the different between this two hook(useMemo and useEffect)

Comment: Well it's be good to check the docs (https://react.dev/reference/react/hooks) for each to see what they are and the difference will become obvious. Basically for each render, `useEffect` is for executing code and `useMemo` is for caching a value. Check examples of each and Google some basic articles covering core React hooks

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` and `useMemo` are re-render depending on its dependency change.

But `useEffect` is for handling side effects and does not returning any value

```
 useEffect(()=>{
    const timer = setInterval(() => {
      setIsMounted(true);
    }, 1000);

    return () => {
      clearInterval(timer);
    };
 },[])
```

And `useMemo` is for caching a calculation between re-render

```
//caching the value returned from function getValueByState 
const value = useMemo(
    () => getValueByState(state),
    [state]
  );
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation sir, but i want to ask another question, does useMemo, useEffect and useCallback will be execute and return when the component rendered for the first time ?

Comment: Yes, they all execute when the component first rendered

Comment: Yes, and whenever the dependencies change.